# Add variable on Column based on input and display the actual value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to assign a variable on my field to change the MONTH char, I have 3 fields `[PRODUCT 1 - JAN - Q1 TARGET]` , `[PRODUCT 1 - FEB- Q1 TARGET]` and `[PRODUCT 1 - MAR- Q1 TARGET]` depends on my input but when I tried to use the `+` to merge the variable `'[PRODUCT 1 - '+@MONTH+'- Q1 TARGET]'` it just display the text and not the value of my field.

```
DECLARE @MONTH CHAR(3),
        @YEAR INT
SELECT
    [CODE],
    @MONTH TARGETMONTH,
    @YEAR TARGETYEAR,
    [PRODUCT 1 - FEB - Q1 TARGET] TARGET
FROM
    QUARTER1_TARGET
```

Comment: You need to explain further what you are trying to do. Your question would benefit from some sample data and expected results to clarify what exactly you want.

Comment: Looks like you are having `month` (JAN, FEB etc) as your column name in your table. Do consider changing your table design and normalize it

Comment: @DaleK, I added some information, basically i just want the month to be dynamic and display the actual value based on my table.

Comment: @Squirrel, thanks yes that's correct but unfortunately that table is not mine, I have no choice but to work on that table.

Comment: @Trunks sample data + expected results please. I know it all makes sense to you, but we are not familiar with your situation and data speaks louder than words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `CASE` expression to return the required column

```
SELECT CASE @Month
       WHEN 'JAN' THEN [PRODUCT 1 - JAN - Q1 TARGET]
       WHEN 'FEB' THEN [PRODUCT 1 - FEB - Q1 TARGET]
       WHEN 'MAR' THEN [PRODUCT 1 - MAR - Q1 TARGET]
       END AS TARGET
```

Seriously you should really consider normalize your table

Comment: I am impressed that you figured out what the OP was asking!